# How long do Teltior live?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Is the lifespan of the Teltior mentioned anywhere in the Star Wars canon or EU? Do any sources give any indication as to how long they might be expected to hang around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this one is "don't know". The [Teltior](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Teltior) (and their companion species, the Meris) appear in a [number](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Planets_of_the_Galaxy,_Volume_Three) of [RPG](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars_Planets_Collection) sourcebooks, but [none](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galaxy_Guide_2:_Yavin_and_Bespin_(Second_Edition)) of these [give](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shadows_of_the_Empire_Planets_Guide) any indication of their likely lifespan.

They have excellent medical knowledge and are relatively hardy. Since their longevity is not worthy of mention (either as a positive or negative feature of the species makeup), you'd expect them to have *at least* a normal average humanoid lifespan of 70-100 years.

Comment: Makes sense - cheers, I'll take that. :-)